# Angular load content without page reload

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have the following route defined. My initial view is CategoryComponent. When somebody clicks a category i want to render the ProductComponent without reloading in the same area where categories are listed. How can i do this ?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MarketComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'categories',
        component: CategoryComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'category/:id/products',
        component: ProductComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

My category url is `http://localhost:4200/market/categories` and my Product url is `http://localhost:4200/market/category/1234/products`

Comment: It seems like you have **CategoryComponent** as Tabs and **ProductComponent** as content/description of that category. If that is correct, you can simply pass different values for the params of **ProductComponent**. This way you will only re-render ProductComponent.

Answer (score 0):

use something like
you will need to collate both the components into 1 .

current page


new page page

change the value of X to render divs.

Answer (score 0):

I make demo project. Please open and check the solution
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-routin?file=src/app/app.component.ts